# Allow flexible csv structure import into partitioned bigquery table from gcs

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery, gsutil

I have a partitioned table in bigquery that gets refreshed weekly with csv files from google cloud storage.  During the refresh process the entire table is deleted and rewritten.

A new column was added to the csv files and the table structure was updated accordingly, but now during the refresh I get a column mismatch error because the old csv files don't contain the new column.

Is there a way to use gsutil or bq command line to smoothly add the column to the old csv files during the import into the partitioned table without having to download each file onto my local computer and alter the csv's one by one?